# Electron source code Windows vscode debug

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, electron, chromium

I have already downloaded the source code for Electron on Windows and can also compile Electron.exe. Now I want to debug in vscode, but this step is stuck. Running the following command in powershell can compile successfully:

```
mkdir electron
cd electron

gclient config --name "src/electron" --unmanaged https://github.com/electron/electron@v29.1.1
gclient sync --with_branch_heads --with_tags

cd src
$env:CHROMIUM_BUILDTOOLS_PATH = "$(Get-Location)\buildtools"

gn gen out/Testing --args="import(\`"//electron/build/args/testing.gn\`")"
ninja -C out/Testing electron
```

How should I configure in VSCODE to debug?

I added the following launch.json in the Electron root directory, But it doesn't take effect

- .vscode/launch.json

```
{
  // 使用 IntelliSense 了解相关属性。
  // 悬停以查看现有属性的描述。
  // 欲了解更多信息，请访问: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "(Windows) Launch",
      "type": "cppvsdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\src\\out\\Testing\\electron.exe",
      "args": ["demo"],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "environment": [
        { "name": "ELECTRON_ENABLE_LOGGING", "value": "true" },
        { "name": "ELECTRON_ENABLE_STACK_DUMPING", "value": "true" },
        { "name": "ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE", "value": "" }
      ],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "sourceFileMap": {
        "o:\\": "${workspaceFolder}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

- Directory Structure

```
.
|-.vscode
|-src/
|-demo/
└-.gclient
```